# preg_match skipping comma for decimals match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I got this condition:

```
    if ( preg_match( '/class="count">\((\d+)\)/', $view, $matches ) ) {
    return absint( $matches[1] );
}
```

asssuming

```
$view = '<a href='users.php?role=wpsc_anonymous'>Anonymous <span class="count">(2,391)</span></a>';
```

This should return 2390 correct ? But it is not.

Comment: You're only matching decimals, not any optional `,` - and a preg_match won't filter that out.

Comment: Is my code as it is now supposed to return 2,390 ? the value between the brackets ? cause thats what i need

Answer (score 0):

`,` is not a numeric character, and therefore is not matched by `\d`.

Try `[0-9,]` instead of `\d`, and make sure you strip out the comma before trying to convert it to an integer.

Comment: No. It is a trivial operation that you should be able to figure out with a minimum of effort.